# Нахождение координат вершин прямоугольника ( заданы две вершины и даигональ )

Tags: python

Сделал программу в Flowgorithm, но наверное не правильно прописал все формулы для нахождения двух координат... намудрил с математикой ... прошу помочь разобраться

В декартовых координатах указаны вершины A и B прямоугольника ABCD и длина диагонали (вершины ориентированы против часовой стрелки). Напишите программу, которая считывает у пользователя координаты Ax, Ay, Bx, By и длину диагонали и выводит координаты остальных вершин C и D, округленные до двух знаков после запятой в формате

```
Cx = ...
Cy = ...
Dx = ...
Dy = ...

Пример:
Входные данные
0
0
4
0
5

Выход

Cx = 4.00
Cy = 3.00
Dx = 0.00
Dy = 3.00

Мой код:
    ax = float(input())
    ay = float(input())
    bx = float(input())
    by = float(input())
    dI = float(input())
    
    aB = sqrt((bx - ax) ** 2 + (by - ay) ** 2) # формула нахождения длины стороны прямоугольника
    bC = sqrt(dI ** 2 - aB ** 2)               # формула нахождения одного катета        
    cx = aB
    cy = bC
    dy = bC
    dx = ax
    print("Сх = " + toFixed(cx,2))     
    print("Сy = " + toFixed(cy,2))
    print("Dx = " + toFixed(dx,2))
    print("Dy = " + toFixed(dy,2))
```

Comment: Читайте https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-remaining-vertices-of-a-square-from-two-given-vertices/

Comment: А где же `формулы для нахождения двух координат`? Всегда ли прямоугольник ориентирован вдоль осей координат?

Comment: да вот наверное не всегда ... я пока не знаю ... я над этим решением часа 4 думал наверное ... не сразу увидел там треугольник ... щас наверное возьму небольшую паузу .. а то мозг кипит уже )) + смотрю первую ссылку которую дали в первом комментарии